# How to disable button based on current date and time using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have store list with details.i have stored day wise shop open time and close time .here i need to take current day and current time and check with every store date and time(i have store opening day with open time and close time).if current day time match with store open time order button should enable.if current date and time not matcehed i need to disable button.i new to technology  pls some one help me out

Example :today is tuesday if time is 08.00PM only one store order button should enable ragu mobile service center order button demo [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rpbn6u23/31/).i have tried to take day and time but i can't able to take bcoz i am beginner pls some one help me out for this task.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller("myCntrl", function ($scope,$filter) {
  
    $scope.dealers = [{
        
        S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "samsung",
  status:"",
        Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
  Day: {
        "monday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "tuesday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "wednesday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "thursday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "friday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "saturday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM",
  "sunday":"10:15AM - 04:15PM"
  },
    }, {
       
        S_Email_id: "rajs@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia",
  status:"",
        Store_Name: "sri shakthi mobile service",
        S_Services: "Settings Faults,Regular Service,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
  Day: {
        "monday": "09:00AM - 06:00PM",
        "tuesday": "09:00AM - 06:00PM",
        "wednesday": "09:00AM - 06:00PM",
        "thursday": "09:00AM - 06:00PM",
        "friday": "09:00AM - 06:00PM",
        "saturday": "09:00AM - 06:00PM",
  "sunday":"Leave"
  },
  
    }, {
        
        S_Email_id: "sprtive23@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia,samsung",
  status:"",
        Store_Name: "sun mobile service center",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,overall maintenance,Mobile Shield Installation",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
  Day: {
        "monday": "08:30AM - 07:30PM",
        "tuesday": "08:30AM - 07:30PM",
        "wednesday": "08:30AM - 07:30PM",
        "thursday": "08:30AM - 07:30PM",
        "friday": "08:30AM - 07:30PM",
        "saturday": "08:15AM - 02:15PM",
  "sunday":"8:15AM - 12:15AM"
  },
  
  },
 {
        
        S_Email_id: "super@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia,samsung",
  status:"",
        Store_Name: "ragu mobile service center",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,overall maintenance,Mobile Shield Installation",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
  Day: {
        "monday": "10:00AM - 10:00PM",
        "tuesday": "10:00AM - 10:00PM",
        "wednesday": "10:00AM - 10:00PM",
        "thursday": "10:00AM - 10:00PM",
        "friday": "10:00AM - 10:00PM",
        "saturday": "leave",
  "sunday":"leave"
  },
  
  
  }
    ]
 var date = new Date();
 
 $scope.hhmmsstt = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'hh:mm:ss a');
 //console.log($scope.hhmmsstt);
 }
)
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
        <label>Search on Label</label><br>
        <input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Search for name" />
        <br><br>
        
            <div ng-repeat="dealer in dealers">
                          
                {{dealer.Store_Name}}<br>
    {{dealer.S_Email_id}}<br>
    {{dealer.Day}}<br>
                <input type="button" value="order"/>
    <br><br><br>
                    
    </div>
    
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `ng-disabled` on your `input` button, with an expression comparing Today with the day of week inside `dealer.Day`, Then you have to split the day value by " - " to get the begin and end time, and check if now is between those two times. It needs date conversion and parsing.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("myCntrl", function($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.isOpen = function(dealerSchedule) {
      var now = new Date();
      // 09:10AM - 06:30PM
      var times = dealerSchedule[Object.keys(dealerSchedule)[now.getDay() - 1]].replace(/(\d\d\:\d\d)(AM|PM)/g, '1/1/1900 $1 $2').split(" - ");
      var nowTime = new Date('1/1/1900 ' + now.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        hour12: true
      }));
      return nowTime >= new Date(times[0]) && nowTime <= new Date(times[1]);
    };

    $scope.dealers = [{

      S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com",
      S_Store: "samsung",
      status: "",
      Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store",
      S_Services: "Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults",
      Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
      Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
      Day: {
        "monday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "tuesday": "09:10AM - 12:00PM",
        "wednesday": "09:10AM - 10:30AM",
        "thursday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "friday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "saturday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM",
        "sunday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM"
      },
    }, {

      S_Email_id: "rajs@gmail.com",
      S_Store: "nokia",
      status: "",
      Store_Name: "sri shakthi mobile service",
      S_Services: "Settings Faults,Regular Service,Hardware Faults",
      Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
      Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
      Day: {
        "monday": "09:00AM - 06:00PM",
        "tuesday": "09:00AM - 06:00PM",
        "wednesday": "09:00AM - 06:00PM",
        "thursday": "09:00AM - 06:00PM",
        "friday": "09:00AM - 06:00PM",
        "saturday": "09:00AM - 06:00PM",
        "sunday": "Leave"
      },

    }, {

      S_Email_id: "sprtive23@gmail.com",
      S_Store: "nokia,samsung",
      status: "",
      Store_Name: "sun mobile service center",
      S_Services: "Regular Service,overall maintenance,Mobile Shield Installation",
      Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
      Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
      Day: {
        "monday": "08:30AM - 07:30PM",
        "tuesday": "02:30PM - 07:30PM",
        "wednesday": "08:30AM - 07:30PM",
        "thursday": "08:30AM - 07:30PM",
        "friday": "08:30AM - 07:30PM",
        "saturday": "08:15AM - 02:15PM",
        "sunday": "8:15AM - 12:15AM"
      },

    }, {

      S_Email_id: "super@gmail.com",
      S_Store: "nokia,samsung",
      status: "",
      Store_Name: "ragu mobile service center",
      S_Services: "Regular Service,overall maintenance,Mobile Shield Installation",
      Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
      Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
      Day: {
        "monday": "10:00AM - 10:00PM",
        "tuesday": "10:00AM - 10:00PM",
        "wednesday": "10:00AM - 10:00PM",
        "thursday": "10:00AM - 10:00PM",
        "friday": "10:00AM - 10:00PM",
        "saturday": "leave",
        "sunday": "leave"
      },


    }]
    var date = new Date();

    $scope.hhmmsstt = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'hh:mm:ss a');
    //console.log($scope.hhmmsstt);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
    <label>Search on Label</label>
    <br>
    <input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Search for name" />
    <br>
    <br>

    <div ng-repeat="dealer in dealers">

      {{dealer.Store_Name}}
      <br>{{dealer.S_Email_id}}
      <br>{{dealer.Day}}
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="order" ng-disabled="!isOpen(dealer.Day)" />
      <span>{{isOpen(dealer.Day) ? 'Open' : 'Closed'}}</span>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i need one more thing how to show status like shop opened now or shop closed now in store list

Comment: @martin, just use a `<span>{{isOpen(dealer.Day) ? 'Open' : 'Closed'}}</span>`